# Need information on didgital picture frame

Tags: photography, display

Recently, I purchased a [Forc Digital Picture Frame, 15.6 Inch Digital Photo Frame, 1920x1080](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0BZP3H1SZ). It works well for the intended purpose, but it is tempting to expand its functionality. The device has USB input and output connectors, and WiFi... it would be nice to use it as a display, or even a low-end Android PC.

However, I cannot find any information on the the frame, despite searches for *Forc*or  for Shenzhen JENO Technology Co., Ltd. (the only name on the shipping box). It uses Uhale (previously known as *Whale*) apps for phone connectivity, for which I have no need.

Does anyone have information on the hardware, or on hacking this Android device to increase its usefulness? (BTW, at the time of purchase it was ~US$80, and has *doubled* since then! Not such a bargain to buy, now.)